# Accordian Section, click an image to rotate an icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a solution to a little problem, complete novice, built my first site. I have utilized the "Summary-Details" feature, and included an image, which meant the stock dropdown arrow was moved, to which I couldn't position where I wanted it to be. I added an icon from material-icons, and I would like this to rotate when the whole image/section is clicked. I won't include any JS as I'm probably miles away from where I should be. Any help much appreciated.

```css
.card {
    width: 18em;
    justify-self: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em 1em 0;
}


.card img {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    width: 18em;
    height: auto;
}

summary {
    width: 18em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
    color: #202020;
    background: #808080;
    
    cursor: pointer;
    
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display: none;
}

.card i {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-variant-position: sub;
    color: #101010;
}

.card i:active{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    color: #fef;
}

summary:focus {
    outline-style: none;
    background: #404040;
    color: #fef;
}

details {
    width: 17.55em;
    color: #fef;
    background: #212529;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -.25em 0 2em;
    border-right: solid 1px #b5b5b5;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #b5b5b5;
}

.contentul li {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" id="card" >
                        <details>
                            <summary><img id="img1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503708928676-1cb796a0891e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1334&q=80" alt="ex1">Excavators<br><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></summary>
                                <ul class="contentul">
                                    <li>180° Wheeled</li>
                                    <li>360° Wheeled</li>
                                    <li>360° Tracked</li>
                                </ul>
                        </details>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Rotate how? It begins pointing down. Which direction should it be pointed when it completes?

Comment: Sorry, should've included that. Rotate by 180 degrees. Just as an indicator that the section expands and contracts.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer. It uses no `JavaScript` and only one character. Plus, you have the option of using movement in the chevron rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `JavaScript` to accomplish this. The `translateY` bit is used to keep the icon from rotating away from its starting position. The value `0.5em` means *half the height of the box containing the chevron*.

```css
.fas.fa-chevron-down {
  transition: .15s transform ease-in-out;
}

details[open] .fas.fa-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-0.5em);
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.card {
  width: 18em;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em 1em 0;
}

.card img {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 18em;
  height: auto;
}

summary {
  width: 18em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #202020;
  background: #808080;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

.card i {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-variant-position: sub;
  color: #101010;
}

.card i:active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  color: #fef;
}

summary:focus {
  outline-style: none;
  background: #404040;
  color: #fef;
}

details {
  width: 17.55em;
  color: #fef;
  background: #212529;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -.25em 0 2em;
  border-right: solid 1px #b5b5b5;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #b5b5b5;
}

.contentul li {
  padding: 1em;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-down {
  transition: .15s transform ease-in-out;
}

details[open] .fas.fa-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-0.5em);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" id="card">
  <details>
    <summary><img id="img1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503708928676-1cb796a0891e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1334&q=80" alt="ex1">Excavators<br><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></summary>
    <ul class="contentul">
      <li>180° Wheeled</li>
      <li>360° Wheeled</li>
      <li>360° Tracked</li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant. I thought it must be possible to do it without JS, but i mustn't have been asking the right questions whilst searching.

Comment: @PaulMack Thanks for taking another look at it.